# How can I defer delivery of an email message with exim?

Tags: email, sendmail, exim

I have previously used sendmail from the command line to send a large number of messages and used the -odd flag to defer delivery so that the program puts the emails into the queue quickly and returns to the user while messages are delivered in the background. This is described in the DeliveryMode portion of the man page:

http://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/man/sendmail.html

The new server I am moving to is using exim and sendmail is aliased to exim, and is choking on the -odd flag. Is there a way to force exim to perform a deferred delivery on a message from the command line and put it into the queue instead of immediately trying to deliver it?

Comment: Thanks so much for this, I've been searching for sendmail command line options for delayed sending EVERYWHERE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have your tried/considered using exim supported `-odq`? (or exim specific `-odqs`)

Sendmail's `-odd` puts messages in queue like `-odq` and avoids doing any DNS loops.

[The Exim command line](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_exim_command_line.html)

> -odq  This option applies to all modes in which Exim accepts incoming messages, including the listening daemon. It specifies that the accepting process should not automatically start a delivery process for each message received. Messages are placed on the queue, and remain there until a subsequent queue runner process encounters them. There are several configuration options (such as queue_only) that can be used to queue incoming messages under certain conditions. This option overrides all of them and also -odqs. It always forces queueing.

Comment: If messages will be delivered to remote hosts also `-odqs` can be interesting.

Comment: They are actually only being delivered to remote hosts, so I think the distinction offered between odq and odqs is not too important for my use case, but thanks! Appreciate the response, Andrzej!